# icono de busqueda no se muestra al principio

Tags: java, android, searchview

tengo varias fragments y activities en mi app, en las que he implementado searchview y funciona todo correctamente, el problema sucede en una nueva vista en la que lo quiero implementar en donde aparece solo la toolbar sola, sin el icono, pero si cambio de seccion y vuelvo a entrar ya aparece y no se por que si todo esta igual, alguien tiene idea de por que?

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".ManageFragments.MainActivity">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:title="@string/action_search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**Search_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/GrayBackground"
    tools:context=".HomeFragments.SearchFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
  final MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
        //final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit( String query)
            {
                final GifTextView loading = (GifTextView)FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingSearch);
                final TextView loadingText = (TextView)FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingTextSearch);
                final ImageView loadingBackground = (ImageView)FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgGrayBackgroundSearch);
                loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Toast.makeText(SearchFragment.this.getActivity(), R.string.buscado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                new PlifRequestBase(getActivity()){
                    @Override
                    public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
                    {
                        JsonObject data, pagination_details = null, businesses, cover_premium, cv, iurl;
                        JsonArray premiums, basics;
                        if (response.get("pagination") == null)
                        {
                            data =  response;
                        }else {
                            pagination_details = response.get("pagination").getAsJsonObject();
                            data = response.get("data").getAsJsonObject();

                            businesses = data.get("businesses").getAsJsonObject();
                            premiums = businesses.get("premiums").getAsJsonArray();
                            basics = businesses.get("basics").getAsJsonArray();

                            gson = new Gson();
                            arrayBusiness = new ArrayList<Business>();
                            arrayBasics= new ArrayList<Business>();

                            arrayBusiness = gson.fromJson(premiums, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                            arrayBasics=gson.fromJson(basics, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                            Log.d("size", String.valueOf(arrayBusiness.size()));
                            //Log.d("", String.valueOf(images_premiums));
                            if (getActivity() == null)
                                return response;
                            FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.high_recycler_view);
                                    RecyclerView recyclerbasics=(RecyclerView) FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lower_recycler_view);

                                    SearchHorizontalAdapter adapter = new SearchHorizontalAdapter(getActivity(), arrayBusiness, R.layout.search_high_layout);
                                    SearchVerticalAdapter adapterbasics=new SearchVerticalAdapter(getActivity(),arrayBasics,R.layout.search_low_layout);

                                    recyclerbasics.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                                    recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

                                    mLowerLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(FeedsFragment.this.getActivity(),2);
                                    recyclerbasics.setLayoutManager(mLowerLayoutManager);
                                    recyclerbasics.setAdapter(adapterbasics);

                                    mLayoutManagera = new LinearLayoutManager(FeedsFragment.this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                                    recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagera);
                                    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBusiness.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("Imprime", arrayBusiness.get(i).getName());
                                    }
                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBasics.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("Imprime", arrayBasics.get(i).getName());
                                    }


                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    loadingBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (pagination_details.isJsonNull()){
                            Log.d("Paginacion", pagination_details.toString());
                        }

                        return data;

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpUnprocessableEntity(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                        this.cancel(true);
                        final String error = response.get("errors").toString();
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }.execute("businesses/search", "GET", "q", "\'"+query.replaceAll(" ","&").trim()+"\'");

                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                textView.setText(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        View searchPlate = (View) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.textfield_custom);

        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JBao.jpg en esta imagen se muestra que no sale el icono de busqueda

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmjPr.jpg y aqui ya aparece despues de que navegas en las demas tabs

Comment: No creo llegar a ningun lado solo viendo el XML , si dices que yendo a otra activity y regresando aparece , no creo el error este en el XML.

Comment: agregue el codigo a partir de donde se trabaja con la searchview, es que tengo demasiado codigo, si gustas dime que otra cosa necesitarias ver, por favor  y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Podrías agregar una imagen para saber a que icono te refieres?

Comment: @Jorgesys listo ya agregue los links de las capturas, en mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que estés navegando entre diferentes activities y trabajando con diferentes menú debes hacer lo siguiente:

En el `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Si estás en el `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}
```